# Merging two ruby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Question: Is there a concise way in Ruby (and/or Rails) to merge two objects together?

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out something akin to jQuery's `$.extend()` method, whereas the first object you pass in will have its properties overridden by the second object.

I'm working with a tableless model in Rails 3.2+. When a form submission occurs, the parameters from the submission are used to dynamically populate a User object. That user object is persisted between page requests using Ruby's PStore class, marshalling objects to flat files which can be easily retrieved in the future.

Relevant code:

```
module Itc
  class User
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    include ActionView::Helpers
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    def set_properties( properties = {} )
      properties.each { |k, v|
        class_eval("attr_reader :#{k.to_sym}")
        self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
      } unless properties.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Creation of a user object occurs like this:

```
user = Itc.User.new( params[:user] )
user.save()
```

The `save()` method above is not ActiveRecord's save method, but a method I wrote to do persistence via PStore.

If I have a user object loaded, and I have a form submission, I'd like to do something like this:

```
merged = existingUserObject.merge(User.new(params[:user])
```

and have the outcome of `merged` be a user object, with only properties that were changed in the form submission be updated.

If anyone has any ideas about a better way to do this in general, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it by piggybacking on hash's behaviors. Create a class that takes a hash for the parameter of the `new()` method, and then a `to_h` method that takes an object and generates a hash from the current state of the instance:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(params={})
    @a = params[:a]
    @b = params[:b]
  end

  def to_h
    {
      a: @a,
      b: @b
    }
  end
end

instance_a = Foo.new(a: 1, b:2)
instance_b = Foo.new(a: 1, b:3)

instance_c = Foo.new(instance_a.to_h.merge(instance_b.to_h))
```

Dumping it into IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo
irb(main):002:1>   def initialize(params={})
irb(main):003:2>     @a = params[:a]
irb(main):004:2>     @b = params[:b]
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> 
irb(main):007:1*   def to_h
irb(main):008:2>     {
irb(main):009:3*       a: @a,
irb(main):010:3*       b: @b
irb(main):011:3>     }
irb(main):012:2>   end
irb(main):013:1> end
nil
irb(main):014:0> 
irb(main):015:0* instance_a = Foo.new(a: 1, b:2)
#<Foo:0x1009cfd00
    @a = 1,
    @b = 2
>
irb(main):016:0> instance_b = Foo.new(a: 1, b:3)
#<Foo:0x1009ead08
    @a = 1,
    @b = 3
>
irb(main):017:0> 
irb(main):018:0* instance_c = Foo.new(instance_a.to_h.merge(instance_b.to_h))
#<Foo:0x100a06c60
    @a = 1,
    @b = 3
>
```

Comment: Tin Man, piggybacking off of hash's merge behavior was the way to go. Only caveat was I needed to dynamically set class properties and attribute getters/setters, so my initialize method looked like this: `def initialize( properties = {} )
        properties.each { |k, v|
          class_eval("attr_reader :#{k.to_sym}")
          self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
        } unless properties.nil?
      end`

Comment: That'd work if you don't know in advance what your instance values will be. Personally, I prefer having more control over what my objects contain, but that's the beauty of Ruby, if we code it to be totally dynamic it's happy to oblige. You might also want to consider sub-classing Hash instead for your new object. Hash has some nice features you'd inherit automatically, without having to worry about creating your own `to_h`.

Answer (score 17):

Is `Hash#merge` not what you're looking for? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge.  Seems like you could just go

```
merged = existingUserObject.merge(params[:user])
```

I don't think you need to create an entirely new `User` object since presumably that's what existingUserObject is and you just want to overwrite some properties.

Comment: This should be the answer since it doesn't require any additional class creation and the hash merging functionality is already baked into Ruby 

Comment: yeah agreed - i was googling "ruby equivalent of jquery extend" and never noticed this, as it wasn't the selected answer ;-(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved similar thing with 1 of my model

```
  # merge other_config.attrs into self.attrs, only for nil attrs
  def merge!(other_object)
    return if other_object.nil? || other_object.class != self.class
    self.assign_attributes(self.attributes.slice ('id').merge(other_object.attributes.slice!('id')){|key, oldval, newval|
      oldval.nil? ? newval: oldval
    })
  end
```